# Rails form that saves data to Salesforce and local DB

Tags: account, authentication, ruby-on-rails, id

I have a user registration form that requires certain fields to be saved to different locations. Fields such as email and name need to be used to create a new salesforce object (Account). Email, password and password confirmation need to be saved to the local postgresql database for authentication of the User object. I have Salesforce connected to my rails app with username and password authentication through the databasedotcom gem.

The app I am building involves authenticating users in my Rails application using Devise, and the rest of the app posts and pulls data on those users once they are logged in.

When the user saves the data (email, password, password confirmation and name) I need to create and save two objects. The first is the Account object which is saved in Salesforce with the Name, ID and email field. The second object is a User object that saves the email, password, password confirmation and the Accountid from the account generated in the corresponding Account object.

I am thinking embedded forms would be the best way to handle this. I would have one part of the form submit data to the local db, then the second part of the form would need to copy the email address that was entered above, and have a field for Name. On submit the form would send the data to their respective controllers where it would be handled from there.

Does anyone have any thoughts/experience with this type of process?